# Key press javascript ctrl key

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, ctrl

Can someone please tell me what's going on with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?
I've tried like every answer of questions about this matter - none work!

```
$("body").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 49)
        summon = "SpearMan";
    if (e.which == 50)
        summon = "SwordMan";
    if (e.which == e.ctrlKey) {
        console.log("ctrl");
    }
});
```

Even in w3schools the example they have doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Pressing 1 = spearman, pressing 2 = swordman, pressing ctrl = somethingelse (```e.which == 17```)? Or you want to use ctrl in combination with another key (```e.which == 49 && e.ctrlKey```)?

Answer (score 2):

So I decided to use this plugin
and it didn't work for me because it only helps if I have an 
https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid.
So what I did was to find how it used the ctrl key:

```
$("body").on("keypress", function(e){
        if(!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
            console.log("ctrl");
            gather = true;
        }
});
```